# how to login a Use without asking for a password in ATG?

Tags: authentication, atg

I need to login user depending on some parameter/flag i will be setting, how to log him in without asking for a password?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the the ATG Documentation on [Auto-Login with Cookies](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E52191_02/Platform.11-1/ATGPersProgGuide/html/s0502trackingregisteredusers01.html#s0502autologinwithcookies01) and  [Security Status](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E52191_02/Platform.11-1/ATGPersProgGuide/html/s0502securitystatus01.html).